# how to compute $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(x^2+4x+13)}\,dx, a>0$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to compute this following integral?

$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(x^2+4x+13)}\,dx, a>0$$

So I started finding singularity points $$-2-3i$$ and $$-2+3i$$

After that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm too lazy to do computation, but standard approach would be to transform it by linear substitution to something like $\int \frac{p(y) \sin(by+c)}{y^2+1}$ and keep in mind that $\int\frac{\operatorname{something}}{y^2+1}$ loudly cries out for $\arctan$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing $\sin(ax)=(e^{iax}+e^{-iax})/2i$ and decompose the integral into two parts.

Next, writing the integrals over a finite interval $[-R,R]$ plus the integral along a semi-circunference, which is in the upper half plane for the integral with 
$e^{iax}$ and in the lower half plane for the integral with 
$e^{-iax}$.

Use residue theory to evaluate the integrals in the limit $R\to \infty$.

Comment: I would have guessed there is a solution for the general anti-derivative too, using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral ?

Comment: There's an $i$ missing in your denominator. Also, to simplify the computations a little, use $\sin ax = \operatorname{Im}(e^{iax})$. That way you only need to consider one integral. Also, you need some version of Jordan's lemma to show that the integral over the additional semi-circle tends to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.